# How to fix the height of Map to the screen size in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I am creating the google map using Angular Google Map Component. I want to the google map to my screen size. I tried `height:100%`. But it doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

I followed this tutorial: https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

Map:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: '<agm-map  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker 
        *ngFor="let m of markers;"
        [latitude]="m.lat"
        [longitude]="m.lng"
        [label]="m.label"
        [markerDraggable]="m.draggable">
        <agm-info-window>{{m.tsunami}}</agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
    <agm-circle *ngFor="let m of markers;"
        [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" 
        [radius]="5000"
        [fillColor]="'red'"
        [circleDraggable]="false"
        [editable]="false">
    </agm-circle>
</agm-map>',
  styleUrls: ['agm-map {
  height: 100%;
}']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I will use this selector name to another html

```
<div style="style:300px;"> 
<app-map></app-map> 
</div>
```

` like this.

Comment: Post your Code.

Comment: @Jonny Check my update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 100vh instead of 100%

```
  agm-map {
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

You can use height 100% if you have a parent div `<div id="map"></div>` contain `agm-map` and in your css file

```
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}
agm-map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-dzi5kg?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thank you, This will work. But if I use the  '<app-map></app-map>' (for display the map in another component) it will show the same height. But I need to fix it into div container. No need to show the same height for all components. Thank you so much

Comment: What I can see is map height is not adjustable according to screen. I am looking for responsive solution. If Anyboday have then please let me know